# pcntl_signal(): Error assigning signal

Tags: php, signals

Why happend this error:

Warning: pcntl_signal(): Error assigning signal in ...

In php5 in CLI, the line is:

pcntl_signal(9,"signalHandlerTemp", false);

I try with SIGKILL and true and nothing!

Answer (score 4):

I quote (from the PHP.net comments):
rbotzer at yahoo dot com 22-Jun-2008 06:50
You cannot assign a signal handler for SIGKILL (kill -9)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php

And this seems to be correct, try changing 9 into 'SIGHUP' and try again, your code will now run...

Answer (score 1):

add this code before sig_handler()

```
declare(ticks = 1);
```

..and try again